# Modal does not appear when called via button

Tags: javascript, jquery, twitter-bootstrap

I have 2 buttons to call individual modals with differing ID's. For some reason, only one of the buttons successfully calls its associated modal, the create modal, and when the other button is clicked, nothing appears to happen, but if the create button is clicked, both the create modal and the delete modal appear. My code is below for reference.

```
<div class="container">
 <div class="row">
   <button type="Submit" id="callcreate" class="btn btn-default btn-sm" style="margin-left: 10px; margin-right: 10px;" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#createModal">Create</button> 
   <button type="Submit" id="calldelete" class="btn btn-default btn-sm" style="margin-left: 10px; margin-right: 10px;" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#deleteModal">Delete</button>
 </div>

 <!-- Create Button to create a new profile -->
 <div class="modal fade" id="createModal" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" >
   <div class="modal-dialog">
      <div class="modal-content">
         <div class="modal-header">
            <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-hidden="true">&times;</button>
            <h4 class="modal-title" id="createModalLabel">Create Profile</h4>
         </div>
         <div class="modal-body">
           <form method="" action="" name="requestprofiledata" id="requestprofiledata">
            <div >
              <label for="comment">Details: </label>       
              <table  id="tableID" class="table table-bordered table-hover tablewithtooltip">
                <thead>
                  //blah blah blah table/form stuff
              </table>
           </div>
          </form>
         </div>
         <div class="modal-footer">
            <button type="button" class="btn btn-default btn-default" data-dismiss="modal" name="newProfile" id="newProfile">Save</button>
         </div>
      </div><!-- /.modal-content -->
</div><!-- /.modal -->

<!-- Delete Profile button -->
<div class="modal" id="deleteModal" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" >
  <div class="modal-dialog modal-md">
    <div class="modal-content">         
      <div class="modal-header">
        <h4 class="modal-title" id="deleteModalLabel">Confirmation</h4>
      </div>
      <div class="modal-body" >
        <p>Do you wish to permanently delete this profile?</p>       
      </div>
      <div class="modal-footer">
       <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" data-dismiss="modal">Close</button> 
       <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary" name="deleteprofile" id="deleteprofile">Delete profile</button>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div><!-- /model -->
```

Comment: Submit buttons submit.

Comment: Thank you, I've changed it to type="button" and it still exhibits the same behavior.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Are all your `div` elements properly closed?

Please look for:

```
     </div> <!------ THIS ADDED -->
```

In:

[**DEMO**](http://jsfiddle.net/fiddleyetu/77ctdghe/3/)

[**.... Indented version**](http://jsfiddle.net/fiddleyetu/77ctdghe/4/)

Comment: Yes, they are. I did not include a table that was being displayed below the row of buttons, and thus forgot to include the </div> here before the modals.

Comment: So is it Yes or No? Can you confirm that my demo works as you expected? Check out this indented version: http://jsfiddle.net/fiddleyetu/77ctdghe/4/

Comment: The example provided by @PeterKA is working as expected. You're missing a `</div>` for your first modal. When I copy in some example code from the official Bootstrap documentation for modals, they work perfectly: http://www.bootply.com/l9osZbRAG6. As such, the conclusion is your modals are not properly formed.

Comment: Agreed - PeterKA is correct. You are missing TWO </div> closing tags. If you add those, and remove the table, your example code works.

Comment: Yes, thank you! I didn't have the </div> at the end of the create modal. Thank you so much!

Answer (score 0):

the issue with your code is that youre missing a `</div>` in #createModal  http://jsfiddle.net/swm53ran/103/

```
         </div><!-- /.modal -->
    </div> <!-- Add this one -->
```

And also, youre #deleteModal is missing class fade if you want it to fade in instead of popping up

```
<div class="modal fade" id="deleteModal" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" >
```

also, this doesnt really affect performance, but you're missing a closing head tag `</thead>` in your table